# I am unable to navigate to detail page from List Tile Page and show retrieved data of the particular item

Tags: firebase, flutter, data-retrieval

I have uploaded few text items, image items and pdf documents to firebase database / storage and  and able to retrieve all of them in HomeScreen  i.e Vertical CardsUI list as well as ListTiles  View with one image, one title and one subtitle.

But unable to build DetailView i.e One Singe Item's details instead of  multipleCards and navigate to DetailView page
on click on any List Tile Item  .

My code for HomeScreen.dart is  as follows

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:gadjet_inventory/Form/ListTileFeed.dart';
import 'package:gadjet_inventory/Form/ListTiles.dart';
import 'package:gadjet_inventory/Form/RetrievePage.dart';
import 'package:gadjet_inventory/main.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:gadjet_inventory/Form/Data.dart';

import 'UploadData.dart';

import 'package:pdf_flutter/pdf_flutter.dart';
// ignore: must_be_immutable
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Data> dataList = [];
  List<bool> favList = [];
  bool searchState = false;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String get data => null;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    DatabaseReference referenceData = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Data");
    referenceData.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
      dataList.clear();
      favList.clear();
      var keys = dataSnapShot.value.keys;
      var values = dataSnapShot.value;

      for (var key in keys) {

        Data data = new Data(
            values [key]['imgUrl'],
            values [key]['wcimgUrl'],
            values [key]['wcpdfUrl'],
            values [key]['cattegorrytype'],
            values [key]['companyname'],
           values [key]['modelname'],
            values [key]['seriesname'],
            values [key]['serielnumber'],
            key
          //key is the uploadid
        );
        dataList.add(data);
        auth.currentUser().then((value) {
          DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Data").child(key).child("Fav")
              .child(value.uid).child("state");
          reference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapShot){
            if(snapShot.value!=null){
              if(snapShot.value=="true"){
                favList.add(true);
              }else{
                favList.add(false);
              }
            }else{
              favList.add(false);
            }
          });
        });

      }
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
        setState(() {
          //
        });
      });


    });


  }

  int selectedRadioTile;

  String get path => null;

  String get title => null;

  setSelectedRadioTile(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadioTile = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      //Color(0xffffffff),
      appBar: AppBar(
       centerTitle: true,
       backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: new Text("Device Details", style:
        TextStyle(fontSize: 20), textAlign: TextAlign.center),

        ),

      body: dataList.length == 0
          ? Center(
          child: Text("No Data Available", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),))
          : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: dataList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return CardUI(dataList[index].imgUrl,dataList[index].wcimgUrl, ,dataList[index].wcpdfUrl, dataList[index].cattegorrytype,
                dataList[index].companyname, dataList[index].modelname,dataList[index].seriesname,                dataList[index].uploadid,index);
          }
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget CardUI(String imgUrl, String wcimgUrl, String wcpdfUrl, String cattegorrytype, String companyname, String modelname,
      String seriesname      String uploadId,int index) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 7,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      //color: Color(0xffff2fc3),
      color:Colors.blueGrey,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.5),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              imgUrl != null
                  ? imgUrl
                  : '',
              width: 500,
              height: 500,

            ),


            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

                       child: Text(  "Cattegorry Type:- "
                             "$cattegorrytype",





                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),


                         ),


                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                    child: Text(  "Company Name:- "
                        "$companyname",

                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                      child: Text(  "Model Name:- "
                          "$modelname",


                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                  ),
                 ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                      child: Text(  "Series Name:- "
                          "$seriesname",


                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),


                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),

            RaisedButton(


              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),

              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("Warranty Card",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),),
            ),
            RadioListTile(
              value: 1,
              groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
              title: Text("PDF"),
              //subtitle: Text("Upload PDF File"),
              /*  onChanged: (val) {
                        filePicker(context);
                      },*/
              activeColor: Colors.red,
          ),
         Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)),

          //  _buildPDF1Field(context),
            PDF.network(
              wcpdfUrl != null
                  ? wcpdfUrl
                  : '',

              width: 600,
              height: 1000,     placeHolder: Image.asset("assets/images/pdf.png",
                height: 600, width: 500),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 24),


            RadioListTile(
              value: 2,
              groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
              title: Text("Image"),
              //subtitle: Text("Upload W Card Image"),
              /* onChanged: (val) {
                        openWCImagePickerModal(context);
                        //_startWCUpload();
                      },*/
              activeColor: Colors.blue,


            ),

            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)),

            Image.network(
              wcimgUrl != null
                  ? wcimgUrl
                  : 'https://www.testingxperts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-img.jpg',
              width: 500,
              height: 500,

           ),
          SizedBox(height: 24),



          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}.
```

Now my requirement is to show Detail View of single item  when clciked on it in ListTiles , it should navigate to DetailPage and show me the details of that particular item.

How to build DetailView page ? and Navigate from ListTilePage

Comment: Please read [ask]. *"Please fix my code (ASAP)"* is not how this site works.

Comment: Ok. Why I am seeing a blank screen when navigated to this page.  I am getting the data  by parsing using dataList[index] as described above in the code.

Comment: Are there any errors being printed in your debug console? I think the listview is your problem since it has no bounds around it, like a sizedbox or container with a fixed size.

Comment: Error: Another Exception of Dignostic<void>

Comment: Please fix my issue . i have clearly given my requirements.

Comment: It sounds like you want us to write the code to display a DetailView and navigate to it. SO is for assistance with code you've attempted and are having issues with, not for creating code for you. It's not clear if you've actually attempted that; there's too much code in the question for us to parse through. If you DID attempt to write that code, make that the focus of the question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please understand .I don't want any body to write complete code for me.But asking to give me idea or clue wheter I have to write seperate detailpage.dart or can navigate using HomeScreen.dart keeping any conditions like dataList[index] etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using  seperate DetailView.dart page.

I have created DetailView.dart page separately  like

```
class DetailView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailViewState createState() => _DetailViewState();
}

class _DetailViewState extends State<DetailView> {


  List<Data> dataList = [];
  List<bool> favList = [];
  bool searchState = false;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String get data => null;




}  etc
```